# SystemD Spring Boot Dependencies Wait Fully Up

Tags: spring-boot, systemd

I am bootstrapping my spring boot applications in SystemD. It works great, but I need to figure out how to setup dependencies between the applications to manage startup order.

How can I ensure a service only starts once another is completely up. Ideally by checking the /health url of the service

Comment: For those interested it looks like the preferred method is to add logic to your application to handle dependencies. This was a very useful video to understand better how to handle inter-service dependencies. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=CZ3wIuvmHeM